# how to get content from other site and show it?

Tags: pre-get-posts

i want to get content from other sites and show it on my WordPress site .

example : i want to get Description Text from http://filehippo.com/download_adobe_reader/

and show it on my site .

or add as custom fields !

thanks

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp_remote_get or/and wp_remote_retrieve_body functions to get HTTP response

Retrieve the raw response from the HTTP request using the GET method. Results include HTTP headers and content. codex [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get)

```
$response = wp_remote_get( $url, $args );
```

Retrieves the body of an already retrieved HTTP request. [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_retrieve_body)

```
$the_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get('http://example.com') );
```